# How can I get a procedure to print multiple columns from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am very new to coding with SQL and I was having trouble printing multiple columns from multiple tables in a single procedure. My code compiles the procedure with no problem and executes with no issues but nothing is displayed. I am trying to use PL/SQL to "Print all canceled reservations in the hotel management system. Show reservation ID, hotel name, location, guest name, room type, dates". My aim is to print all those columns listed for rid (202). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
create or replace procedure ShowCancelations (id in int)
IS
p_rid reservation.rid%TYPE;
p_hotel_name hotel.hotel_name%TYPE;
p_street_number hotel.street_number%TYPE;
p_name_street hotel.name_street%TYPE; 
p_name customer.name%TYPE;
p_room_type room.room_type%TYPE;
p_start_date reservation.start_date%TYPE;
p_end_date reservation.end_date%TYPE;

cursor c1 is
Select reservation.rid,hotel_name,street_number,name_street,name,room_type,start_date,end_date
INTO p_rid, p_hotel_name, p_street_number, p_name_street, p_name, p_room_type, p_start_date, p_end_date
From customer,reservation,hotel,room
WHERE reservation.rid = hotel.rid and reservation.cid = customer.cid and reservation.room_id = room.room_id;

begin
if id is not null then
dbms_output.put_line(p_rid);
dbms_output.put_line(p_hotel_name);
dbms_output.put_line(p_street_number);
dbms_output.put_line(p_name_street);
dbms_output.put_line(p_name);
dbms_output.put_line(p_room_type);
dbms_output.put_line(p_start_date);
dbms_output.put_line(p_end_date);
else
dbms_output.put_line('Wrong');
end if;
EXCEPTION
 when No_data_found then
     dbms_output.put_line('no information');
end;

execute ShowCancelations(202);`
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using SQL Server? The syntax doesn't look like it.

Comment: sorry didn't realize what I selected. I am using SQL developer

Comment: Remove cursor c1 is.  Just select into your variables. You don't need a cursor.

Comment: Why not tag your *actual* rdbms?

Comment: SQL Developer is a client application. Tag your question with the DBMS product (looks like Oracle).

Comment: did you set serveroutput on?

Comment: I did set serveroutput on but it still won't print the information. I also tried to remove the cursor and just do a select into statement but the same thing nothing gets printed when I execute the procedure

Comment: Apologies if this is a stupid question, but you are looking in the dbms_output panel and not the panel where you are running the query, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

I made up a test code based on your case.

```
begin
  for r in (select Rv.Rid,
                   h.Hotel_Name,
                   h.Street_Number,
                   h.Name_Street,
                   c.Name,
                   Rm.Room_Type,
                   Rv.Start_Date,
                   Rv.End_Date
              from Customer c, Reservation Rv, Hotel h, Room Rm
             where Rv.Rid = h.Rid
               and Rv.Cid = c.Cid
               and Rv.Room_Id = Rm.Room_Id)
  loop
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(r.Rid);
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(r.Hotel_Name);
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(r.Street_Number);
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(r.Name_Street);
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(r.Name);
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(r.Room_Type);
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(r.Start_Date);
    Dbms_Output.Put_Line(r.End_Date);
  end loop;
end;
```

r is an implicit cursor initialized by the for loop.